# Unable to resolve Amazon route53 domain name to loadbalancer

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-route53

In AWS I have configured a load balancer to point to an EC2 instance and its working fine. Then I used route53 to resolve my domain to the loadbalancer IP. ex: "api.b1.example.com"

The problem is that on some networks it works fine but on other networks it is not able to resolve this and gives a unknown host error. After some time it starts working again and goes off.

I created two more record sets "api.read.b1.example.com" and "api.write.b1.example.com" and pointed them to the same loadbalancer and they are working fine on those networks which were not able to resolve "api.b1.example.com".

Does anyone know what is going wrong? Is there any other settings changes to be made on AWS?
I doubt this is a DNS caching issue because after some time it is able to resolve for a certain time period and then goes off.

Please let me know any areas that I have to look into.

Comment: DNS related issues are difficult to debug without real domain name.

Comment: Hey @dusan.bajic are you talking about the example.com that I used here? That was just for reference. I have a valid domain name.

Comment: Can you share it with us?

Comment: This is for my client and unfortunately I can't share the details.

Comment: When you say they won't resolve, what does that mean?  Do you get noerror with an empty response or nxdomains?  Can you run a dig +trace and provide output and replace with example domains?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked your Name Server settings at your domain registrar? Make sure you only have AWS servers in that list.